# How to have video as a background in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm finding it difficult to search for this, background video searches for iOS typically refer to multitasking and switching apps with video.

I want to know if it's possible to have a video playing full screen without movie player controls, while displaying another view on top of that with logo, buttons, text, etc...

So,
**Background**: 15 second video loop -
**Foreground**: login / signup buttons, logo, etc...

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options, but the simplest will be to use a `MPMoviePlayerController`, with its `repeatMode` property set to loop forever, and its `controlStyle` set to none. That will give you a view with a looped movie with no controls that you can use as a background by adding it to your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

OP here - I was able to display a video full screen using this code (in viewDidLoad):

(don't forget to substantiate player as a property with **MPMoviePlayerController *player;**)

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoname" ofType:@"m4v"]]];

[player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];

player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[myView addSubview:player.view];

[player play];
```

And that worked fine - it displays a video fullscreen without video controls. What I had a problem with was displaying buttons and graphics above that. Even though my view hierarchy had the player.view seemingly behind my view with buttons, I couldn't get the buttons to appear.

I fixed that by adding in:

```
[player.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

Just set the layer you intend to display above the video to an IBOutlet and then use the video view to add that view (overlayView in this case) as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer a way that is portrayed in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2)

basically the idea is to create a gif of your video, crop it to iPhone Screen size and load it into an un-interactive UIWebView. I believe this will get the job done if you don't need any audio, and it's basically done effortlessly.

I hope it helps you =)

Comment: Won't the quality be kind of bad, and the file-size kind of large?